# How does Ahlfors define derivative on a Riemann Surface?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

I'm reading a passage in Ahlfors (3rd Edition page 298) and he says the following:

[image: Ahlfors (3rd Edition page 298)]

He has previously defined $G_0(f)$ to be the connected component of any germ generated by $f$. Then he wants to view $G_0(f)$ as the domain of a multivalued function $f$.

And $\pi$ is the projection from the sheaf to the complex numbers. So if $g$ is a germ centered at $z \in \mathbb{C}$, $\pi(g) = z$.

What does he mean, saying $\theta: G_0(f) = G_0(g)$? Is it supposed to be $\theta: G_0(f) = G_0(g)\rightarrow G_0(f)$?

In what way does this $g$ lead to the definition of a derivative of $f$? Why does $\theta$ have to have those 2 properties?

Comment: What is the def. of $\pi$?

Comment: I'll answer it in the question right now

Comment: I assume $\theta$ may be a chart map which you pre- and post- compose with f or g, to get a map from $\mathbb C$ to itself; that is the only way I know of dealing with differentiability of maps between surfaces/manifolds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notation first: $\mathfrak{S}_0(\mathbf{f}) \neq \mathfrak{G}_0(\mathbf{f})$. It's $S_0$, not $G_0$. Not that it matters, of course.

What matters is that Ahlfors here isn't concerned with abstract Riemann surfaces, but with very special Riemann surfaces that come with a nice projection to $\mathbb{C}$.

> What does he mean, saying $\theta: G_0(f) = G_0(g)$? Is it supposed to be $\theta: G_0(f) = G_0(g)\rightarrow G_0(f)$?

It is supposed to be $\theta \colon \mathfrak{S}_0(\mathbf{f}) \to \mathfrak{S}_0(\mathbf{g})$. I think it is nothing but a typo.

> In what way does this $g$ lead to the definition of a derivative of $f$? Why does $\theta$ have to have those 2 properties?

It's not $\mathbf{g}$, it's $\theta$. Or, more precisely, the existence of such a $\theta$ when $\mathbf{g}$ is the global analytic function arising from the derivative of $\mathbf{f}$.

Abstractly, it is clear that a holomorphic map $\theta \colon X \to Y$ between two Riemann surfaces induces a homomorphism

$$\theta^\ast \colon \mathscr{O}(Y) \to \mathscr{O}(X)$$

by composition, $f \mapsto f\circ\theta$.

Now in the paragraph concerned, we have two Riemann surfaces $\mathfrak{S}_0(\mathbf{f})$ and $\mathfrak{S}_0(\mathbf{g})$ with the special property that the projection $\pi$ (restricted from the sheaf of germs of holomorphic functions to the respective surface) is a coordinate chart around every point of the surface. That means a map $\theta \colon \mathfrak{S}_0(\mathbf{f}) \to \mathfrak{S}_0(\mathbf{g})$ with the two properties $(1)$ and $(2)$ [note that since $\pi$ is a local homeomorphism, continuity of $\theta$ together with property $(1)$ implies that $\theta$ is a local homeomorphism] is a holomorphic map between the two Riemann surfaces.

We need the continuity of $\theta$ since a holomorphic map between Riemann surfaces is in particular continuous, and what we want *is a holomorphic map between Riemann surfaces*. We need that $\theta$ be fibre-preserving (that is, $\pi\bigl\lvert_{\mathfrak{S}_0(\mathbf{g})}\circ\,\theta = \pi\bigl\lvert_{\mathfrak{S}_0(\mathbf{f})}$) on the one hand to obtain the holomorphicity of $\theta$ (from the continuity, since $\pi$ is a local chart), to guarantee that $\theta$ is not constant (every constant map from $\mathfrak{S}_0(\mathbf{f})$ to any other Riemann surface is holomorphic, of course, but neither that map nor its induced pull-backs are very interesting), and so that each point and its image in the Riemann surfaces correspond to the same point in the plane. We get a relation between the branches of $\mathbf{f}$ and the branches of $\mathbf{g}$ only when the map $\theta$ preserves base-points.

Since $\mathbf{g}$ is a holomorphic function on $\mathfrak{S}_0(\mathbf{g})$, its pull-back $\theta^\ast(\mathbf{g}) = \mathbf{g}\circ\theta$ is a holomorphic function on the Riemann surface $\mathfrak{S}_0(\mathbf{f})$ by the above abstract consideration.

For the derivatives, one must then see that there is such a map $\theta \colon \mathfrak{S}_0(\mathbf{f}) \to \mathfrak{S}_0(\mathbf{f'})$. [The case of the higher derivatives follows by iteration/composition of the maps $\theta_n \colon \mathfrak{S}_0(\mathbf{f^{(n)}}) \to \mathfrak{S}_0(\mathbf{f^{(n+1)}})$.]

But, if the germ of $f$ in $z_0$ can be analytically continued along a path $\gamma$, then of course the germ of $f'$ in $z_0$ can be analytically continued along $\gamma$ too. And that furnishes the map $\theta$. If $f_\zeta = (f,\Omega) \in \mathfrak{S}_0(\mathbf{f})$ is a germ/function element obtained by analytic continuation of the germ $(f_0,\Omega_0)$ along a path $\gamma$, then $\theta(f_\zeta)$ is the germ $f'_\zeta$ obtained by analytic continuation of $(f_0',\Omega_0)$ along $\gamma$.

Comment: What does $\mathscr{O}$ mean?

Comment: The space (ring) of holomorphic functions on whatever open subset of $\mathbb{C}$/Riemann surface you look at. Perhaps the denotation used in the book(s) you read was $H(U)$ or $\operatorname{Hol}(U)$.

Comment: I don't think he mentions homorphic maps between Riemann surfaces or holomorphic functions on Riemann surfaces. Could you define these? He talks about sections, which are continuous functions from an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathfrak{S}$ - maybe these are holomorphic functions on a Riemann surface?

Comment: The homomorphism part is "ring homomorphism". For holomorphic functions $f,g$ on $Y$, you have $(f+g)\circ\theta = (f\circ\theta) + (g\circ\theta)$ and $(f\cdot g)\circ\theta = (f\circ\theta)\cdot(g\circ\theta)$. Regarding holomorphic maps between Riemann surfaces, let me first ask whether you know what a manifold is, and what a differentiable map between differentiable manifolds is? If you do, it's simple to explain, replace "differentiable" with "complex differentiable" everywhere. If you don't, I need to say a lot more.

Comment: And just to mention it, the sections are holomorphic maps from an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ to the Riemann surface $\mathfrak{S}$.

Comment: I think I understand better the motivation behind $\theta$. We want $g \circ \theta$ to have a bunch of nice properties which curiously Ahlfors never talks about. He never mentions the differentiable structure of sheaves $\mathfrak{S_0}(f)$ or why it's useful to preserve base points. I still really don't understand what's the point of preserving base points. Wouldn't we still have a holomorphic function $g \circ \theta$ if $\theta$ was holomorphic but did not preserve base points?

Comment: Yes, $g\circ\theta$ would still be holomorphic if $\theta$ didn't preserve base points (but of course it must still be holomorphic), but the function $\mathbf{g}$ on $\mathfrak{S}_0(\mathbf{g})$ is not just any holomorphic function on some Riemann surface, it is a "multivalued function" on some subset of the plane, and we want to view it as the family of branches of $g$ on (a subset of) the plane. If $\theta$ doesn't preserve base points, the connection to the function(s) on the plane is lost.

Comment: So the idea is that you will be able to find a branch of $g$ on the same set as you are able to find a branch of $f$, as long as such a $\theta$ exists?

Comment: Yes. But it can be that $g$ has no real "branches", for example if $f$ is the logarithm, and $g = f'$, then $g$ is unambiguously defined on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, and $\mathfrak{S}_0(\mathbf{g})$ is a single-sheeted covering of that, while the surface of the logarithm has infinitely many sheets above each point. The existence of such a $\theta$ implies that you can analytically continue $g$ along any path you can continue $f$ along, and whenever an analytic continuation of $f$ returns to the original germ, so does the analytic continuation of $g$ along that path.